# SwiftUI Unknown Attribute 'Observable Object'

Tags: swiftui

So I'm getting the error Unknown attribute `ObservableObject` next to the `@ObservableObject var dataSource = DataSource()` call below. the `ObservableObject` worked perfectly a couple days ago in another project but not anymore.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


class DataSource: ObservableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()


    var expenses = [Expense]() {
        willSet { willChange.send() }
    }
    var savingsItems = [SavingsItem](){
        willSet { willChange.send() }
    }

    //@State var monthlyIncomeText: String
    //var monthlyIncome: Int = 1364


    init(){
        addNewExpense(withName: "Spotify", price: 14)

    }

    func addNewExpense(withName name: String, price: Int){
        let newExpense = Expense(name: name, price: price)
        expenses.append(newExpense)
    }

     func addNewSavingsItem(withName name: String, price: Int, percentage: Double){
        let newSavingsItem = SavingsItem(name: name, price: price, timeTilCompletion: 0, percentage: percentage)
        savingsItems.append(newSavingsItem)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservableObject var dataSource = DataSource()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Expenses")
            List(dataSource.expenses) { expense in
                ExpenseRow(expense: expense)
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Isn’t that the one which got changed to ‘@ObservedObject’?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ObservableObject` is a protocol that `ObservedObject`s must conform to. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) for documentation on `ObservableObject`, and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) for documentation on `ObservedObject`, which is the property wrapper that you are looking for. Change your `ContentView` code to this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var dataSource = DataSource()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Expenses")
            List(dataSource.expenses) { expense in
                ExpenseRow(expense: expense)
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just in case someone runs across this... DO NOT DO THIS.

A new instance of DataSource() will be created each and every time your view definition is evaluated. Use @StateObject introduced in SwiftUI 2 instead.