# @State variable is cleared once new SwiftUI view has been fully loaded

Tags: swiftui

Whenever I call the view CardronaView() the @State variable will be loaded with the correct data for about 3 seconds then it will be reset back to it's default which is an empty string. How can I fix this? I am calling the new view with this:

```
NavigationView {
            List {
                // MARK: - Display Cardrona
                NavigationLink(destination: CardronaView()) {
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Image("Cardrona-header")
                        Text("Cardrona").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Text(cardTemp).foregroundColor(Color.black).padding(.top, 50).font(.title3)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code in the new view is this:

```
struct CardronaView: View {
    
    @State var cardDate: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(cardDate)
        }.onAppear {
            Api().getJsonCard { (Cardrona) in
                cardDate = "\(Cardrona.data_updated)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would get better results if you where passing the data from fist view via a data model of some kind.  Also using some thing like this cloud be a better approach  [@ObservedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58386313/4080925)

Answer (score 0):

When making a network request, it is good practice to perform it before loading the next view. There are many good reasons to do so, as in case the call is not successful, the new view is not loaded and avoid a bad user experience. This is where you show an alert to your user saying that the call couldn't be made.

If the network call succeeds, you pass your result to the new view and populate it.

As a network call is asynchronous and you make this call .onAppear, if the call is taking too long, you will see the empty String because your view as already been loaded.

I changed your code in a way that the network call is being made on the precedent view. But maybe you should add the code when the user taps the ListCell and if the call is successful, then the NavigationLink triggers its destination parameter, which is CardonaView(cardDate:).

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var cardDate: String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        // MARK: - Display Cardrona
        NavigationLink(destination: CardronaView(cardDate: cardDate)) {
          ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Image("Cardrona-header")
            Text("Cardrona").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text(cardTemp).foregroundColor(Color.black).padding(.top, 50).font(.title3)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      Api().getJsonCard { (Cardrona) in
        cardDate = "\(Cardrona.data_updated)"
    }
  }
}

struct CardronaView: View {
  
  var cardDate: String
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Text(cardDate)
    }
  }
}
```